# Problems editing target in project properties

Tags: android

I have a library project whose target in project.properties is `android-11`. I wanted to create an app which uses that library, but compatible with android 4.1.2, so i edited also the library target with `android-16`.
But when i've done this change, the application gave me some problems and didn't work as before: for example in devices with software menu buttons, the buttons did not appear.
Can you tell me why? Thanks

Comment: You do not need to change the library's target version. As long as the library's manifest does not specify a maximum version, it will work with all future versions of Android.

Answer (score 2):

first of all pls goto the SDK manager and check if you have SDK for Android 16 or above installed. If not please install it, if you have already installed then don't change anything in then project.properties, goto AndroidManifest.xml and make sure that "maxSdkVersion" is equal to above 16, if not it means that the library is depreciated and you cannnot use it for latest version. But generally most of the old libraries would support new SDK builds, so I suggest you to leave it as android-11 as it makes no harm

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Comment: ok,thanks. But what if I wanted to add for example an Easy Share Action, which is available from API Level 14?